# PHP - Rerun query with different variables

Tags: php, sql, vtiger

I'm trying to make a simpler version of

```
$query1 = "SELECT $select FROM HelpDesk ORDER BY createdtime DESC LIMIT 100";
$records1 = $client->doQuery($query);
$query2 = "SELECT $select FROM HelpDesk ORDER BY createdtime DESC LIMIT 100,100";
$records2 = $client->doQuery($query2);
```

What I'm looking to do is run it so that it's something like

```
$qnum = 1; qmax = 15; $offset = 100;
while (qnum < $qmax) {
$query# = "SELECT $select FROM Table ORDER BY Field DESC LIMIT 100,$offset";
$records# = $client->doQuery($query#);
}

$records = array_merge($records[]);
```

Now I know this is horrible, but I'm just trying to get across what I'm trying to do.

I'm fairly new to arrays, and I know I need a for or foreach in there for the offset. I'm just unsure how to do it.

Thanks to Chococroc The code I'm now using is:

```
$query1 = "SELECT $select FROM HelpDesk ORDER BY createdtime DESC LIMIT 100";
$records1 = $client->doQuery($query1);
$records = array();
for ($i = 100; $i <= 1500; $i+=100 ) {
 $query      = "SELECT $select FROM HelpDesk ORDER BY createdtime DESC LIMIT 100,$i";
 $new_records = $client->doQuery($query);
 $records     = array_merge($records, $new_records);
}
$records     = array_merge($records, $records1);
```

I did set it originally to $i = 0 but it seemed to skip a row or 3 (depending on the refresh).

Comment: And before others mention it, I know doing 100 records at a time is a pain, but it's what is limit in the vtiger webservice api.

Comment: there are so much records in you query

Comment: If you are going to query all the records anyways, I don't think it will improve overall performance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, but I have to search 1000 (10 queries) right now, and I'm limited to 100 per query.

Comment: Yeah, the loop won't help anything. If you want to improve speed, ask yourself what kind of index you're using in your field createdtime. Maybe, even `id` field (is defined) is better, as it's probably an auto increment that grows up with time

Comment: Ahms, that's another thing... Well, try it with the loops below, XD

Comment: If I could use strait mysql, I'd be done, it's the webservice query stuff that's throwing me. I'm about to try your example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you now where you start, and where you finish, just use a `for` loop:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 100; $i <= 1500; $i+=100 ) {
    $query      = "SELECT $select FROM HelpDesk ORDER BY createdtime DESC LIMIT $i, 100";
    $new_result = $client->doQuery($query);
    $result     = array_merge($result, $new_result);
}
```

Be aware of the offset, it's the first parameter in the limit.

Comment: That seems to answer part of the question, but how do I export all the results (which are arrays) without specifying separate variables for the $query and $records?

Comment: check the update, XD, just merge them as soon as they appears!

Comment: This works, it's giving me odd numbers, but I suspect that's with the rest of the code (I was getting different odd numbers before).